# Multithreading Safe Calls not populating comboboxes vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

just curious on what im doing wrong here, the principle should work. Can anyone give me a hand?

The Code runs fine, but seems to not add them  into my comboboxes

normal thread start like so

```
t1 = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf GetNewClientData))
t1.Start()
```

data is not empty or null... :)

```
Function GetNewClientData()

    Try

        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim myConString As String = My.Settings.ConString
        Dim objcommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand

        With objcommand
            .Connection = con
            Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT distinct Applicant,Client,Market,Project  from AAClient order by Client"
            .CommandText = cmdText

        End With

        con.ConnectionString = myConString
        con.Open()

        Using readerObj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = objcommand.ExecuteReader
            'This will loop through all returned records 
            While readerObj.Read
                addClientInvoke(readerObj("Client").ToString)
                addApplicantInvoke(readerObj("Client").ToString)
                addMarketInvoke(readerObj("Client").ToString)
                addProjectInvoke(readerObj("Client").ToString)
            End While
        End Using

        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return Nothing
End Function

Delegate Sub addApplicant(s As String)
Sub addApplicantInvoke(ByVal s As String)
    If CreateNewSite.cbApplicant.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New addApplicant(AddressOf addApplicantInvoke)
        CreateNewSite.cbApplicant.Invoke(d, New Object() {s})
    Else
        CreateNewSite.cbApplicant.Items.Add(s)
    End If
End Sub

Delegate Sub addClient(s As String)
Sub addClientInvoke(ByVal s As String)
    If CreateNewSite.cbClient.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New addClient(AddressOf addClientInvoke)
        CreateNewSite.cbClient.Invoke(d, New Object() {s})
    Else
        CreateNewSite.cbClient.Items.Add(s)
    End If
End Sub

Delegate Sub addMarket(s As String)
Sub addMarketInvoke(ByVal s As String)
    If CreateNewSite.cbMarket.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New addMarket(AddressOf addMarketInvoke)
        CreateNewSite.cbMarket.Invoke(d, New Object() {s})
    Else
        CreateNewSite.cbMarket.Items.Add(s)
    End If
End Sub

Delegate Sub addProject(s As String)
Sub addProjectInvoke(ByVal s As String)
    If CreateNewSite.cbProject.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New addProject(AddressOf addProjectInvoke)
        CreateNewSite.cbProject.Invoke(d, New Object() {s})
    Else
        CreateNewSite.cbProject.Items.Add(s)
    End If
End Sub
```

possibly how i'm calling the delegate??

any help is appreciated

[image]

**** thanks to @jods here is the working code with one of the invoke methods****

> starting thread in another modul

```
t1 = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf GetNewClientData))
t1.Start(Me)
```

> Code within the Modul

```
Function GetNewClientData(ByVal oldForm As CreateNewSite)

    Try

        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim myConString As String = My.Settings.ConString
        Dim objcommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand

        With objcommand
            .Connection = con
            Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT distinct Applicant,Client,Market,Project from AAClient order by Client"
            .CommandText = cmdText

        End With

        con.ConnectionString = myConString
        con.Open()

        Using readerObj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = objcommand.ExecuteReader
            'This will loop through all returned records 
            While readerObj.Read
                addApplicantInvoke(readerObj("Applicant").ToString, oldForm)
                addClientInvoke(readerObj("Client").ToString)
                addMarketInvoke(readerObj("Market").ToString)
                addProjectInvoke(readerObj("Project").ToString)
            End While
        End Using

        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try

    Return Nothing
End Function

Delegate Sub addApplicant(s As String, oldform As CreateNewSite)
Sub addApplicantInvoke(ByVal s As String, ByVal oldform As CreateNewSite)
    If oldform.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New addApplicant(AddressOf addApplicantInvoke)
        oldform.cbApplicant.Invoke(d, New Object() {s, oldform})
    Else
        oldform.cbApplicant.Items.Add(s)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the ultimate goal here to avoid running this process on the UI thread?

Comment: Yeah, takes to long to load, 10secs - ish ... would like to run in seperate thread then load them in as they come in

Comment: Is this winforms? If so, have you considered a BackgroundWorker? If not, you may want to queue up all your changes for each control into a list that can be applied to the control all at once.

Comment: Not really answering your question, but if you want performance your code is far from optimal. Far too many thread switching going on. Get all your database results and process them so that they are ready to be added in your UI. Then update the UI in a single call.

Comment: That said why your code is not working is not obvious for me. Not sure what I'm missing... Did you put a breakpoint at CreateNewSite.cbProject.Items.Add(s)? Does it hit? What is the value of s at that point?

Comment: @jods yeah i understand, getting it to work first is the issue then optimization, @ joel Coehoorn , no cause i like to keep control of some things and there not very advanced from what i have been reading

Comment: Also not answering the question: get away from Threads and use Tasks. They are more efficient (because of pooling) and much easier to work with.

Comment: @jods ok i will look into tasks, and the comment before yes, it hits the line and has the value it is supposed to and seems to add it , but when it returns the comboboxes are empty

Comment: *Very* strange... If in the debugger you are on the main thread and execute "CreateNewSite.cbMarket.Items.Add(s)" and nothing changes inside the combobox that's pretty much impossible? When do you start your thread? *After* the window has been initialized, right?

Comment: yes after initialization, i can take a picture if you like, but im most certain it hits the line and adds it, as far as im aware the debugger will tell me what thread im in if im in a thread when hovering over the breakpoint ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32358/discussion-between-jods-and-pakk)

Comment: i do get this : Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created. : if i try and force the line CreateNewSite.cbApplicant.Invoke(d, New Object() {s})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `CreateNewSite.cbProject`. CreateNewSite is not your form instance. It's a nifty :p VB.NET feature called the default form instance:

*VB has a concept of "Default Form Instances".  For every Form in the application's namespace, there will be a default instance created in the My namespace under the Forms property.*

You need to pass the correct form instance (i.e. 'Me' / 'this') to your background thread.

Comment: Thanks again for all your effort!